# 'message' is not defined no-undef React Error

Tags: java, reactjs, es6-promise

So basically I am trying to learn promises, The only thing that is bothering me is , I am not able to render the message of promise to the frontend page. Everything else is going fine.I also need to understand what more can we do inside resolve, is it a function ? can we do more activity there ?

```
import "./testAPI.css"
// import react from "react"

function testAPI() {
    let test = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const res = await fetch("/testAPI").then((res) => res.json());
      if(res.status === "Successful"){
        resolve("API Fetch is Successful")
      }
      else {
        reject("Could not fetch API")
      }
    })

    test.then((message) => {
      console.log(message)
      return message;
    }).catch((message) => {
      console.log(message)
    })

    return (
      <>
        <div className="message" >This is message {message} </div>
      </>
    );
}
export default testAPI;
```

The error I am getting is

```
src/components/testAPI/testAPI.js
  Line 24:52:  'message' is not defined  no-undef
```

How to render the message variable's value on the page ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your component to make use of

State - to change the value over time. For example you have a message which doesn't exist unless you made an api call . To preserve the values which changes over time we use state in react . `setMessage` is to trigger a re-render for the component. So you made the API call and have the message but how will the react know that you need to show this message which you got from the Api call ? . so do that react `useState` has the second element in the array a `state updater function`. if you call it the component will re-render causing the UI to be sync in with the latest changes .

useEffect - to trigger the api call when the component is mounted .

```
import "./testAPI.css"
import { useState } from "react"

function testAPI() {
    const [ message , setMessage ] = useState(null);

    const makeApiCall = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("/testAPI").then((res) => res.json());
        const result = await response.json();

        if(result.status === "Successful"){
          setMessage("API Fetch is Successful")
        }
      }catch(error){
        setMessage("Could not fetch API")
      }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        makeApiCall()
    }, [])

    return (
      <>
        { message && (<div className="message" >This is message {message } </div>)}
      </>
    );
}
export default testAPI;
```